# Delete reference cloudwatch-event on removal of aws-lambda using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-lambda

Here is sample ansible tasks:

```
  - lambda:
      name: 'lambdaName'
      state: present
   register: lambdaResult

  - cloudwatchevent_rule:
      name: 'lambdaNameevent'
      targets:
        - arn: '{{ lambdaResult.configuration.function_arn }}'
          id: "1"
```

Everytime I run the above ansible tasks it will create new version of lambda and gives me back "configuration.function_arn" which will be versioned. I use the "function_arn" to create new event.

So, the created event is pointed to 
`arn:aws:lambda:region:somenumber:function:lambdaName:10`

And, when I delete lambda by doing

```
  - lambda:
      name: 'lambdaName'
      state: absent
```

It doesn't remove the referenced event (`lambdaNameevent`).

How do I delete the referenced event on deletion of lambda ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you just have to clean up the cloudwatch event in another task after you remove the lambda

```
- lambda:
    name: 'lambdaName'
    state: absent

- cloudwatchevent_rule:
    name: 'lambdaNameevent'
    state: absent
```

Comment: I was hoping, it will remove the reference. Anyway Thank you :)